# How to split words using JavaScript which contain spaces

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to split an address string into a separate string (Street name, City etc.) after every comma but I need to ignore the white spaces between commas. Is there any way to do that? I tried `stringInput.split(',');` but this doesn't work if the user entered two words for anything.

Example:

```
"No100, Green Lane, Sri Lanka."
```

Expected result:

```
1. No100
2. Green Lane
3. Sri Lanka
```

Comment: without RegEx, you could do that like  `str.split(',').map(s => s.trim());`

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split` method expects a string as the parameter:

```js
let x = 'No100, Green Lane, Sri Lanka';
let y = x.split(', ');
console.log(y);
```

Or if you want to log each word separately:

```js
let x = 'No100, Green Lane, Sri Lanka';
let y = x.split(', ');

y.forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex split on the pattern `,\s*`:

```js
var input = "No100, Green Lane, Sri Lanka";
var parts = input.split(/,\s*/);
console.log(parts);
```